# jQuery - Load website to 0px from top

Tags: jquery, pageload

please check my [website](http://www.dstruning.com) - there's a problem I can't fix. Once you scroll down on the homepage, the #headliner fades out. If you now click another page and after that return back to the homepage, the #headliner is there, again.I know the problem, it's because the #headliner only fades out once the window gets scrolled for 20px.

Is there an action which moves a website always to the top (0px) on load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

It does **exactly** what you want.  When the window loads, the scrollbar will be at the top.

Easy peasy......................................................................................................................